# Any default values that elements fall back on if they are not defined ? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

For instance,

if I specify

```
margin-top: 8px;
margin-left:3em;
margin-right: 10em;
```

what is the value for `margin-bottom` ?

I assumed that it was 0 , but it's not.

Comment: depends on the element... if a DIV its zero... if an input something different depending on the browser

Answer (score 3):

It falls back through all the stylesheets that apply to the document, including the built in one (the [user-agent stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)) that is supplied by the browser vendor (which will have values that vary depending on the element and the browser).

The specification includes [an examples of a default HTML 4 stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html). Open source browsers usually expose their default stylesheets somewhere. See [the WebKit html stylesheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) for example.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely depends on the element, browser, and if the user has a user-agent styulesheet defined. This is why a decent [reset stylesheet](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) is a necessity for web development.

Comment: How do I go about using the reset stylesheet ? Just by pasting it at the start of the CSS ?

Comment: Yes, just make it your first stylesheet.

Answer (score -2):

This is browser specific per element, that's why most developers use a [css reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) stylesheet to set a common value on all browsers.